# Multiple HITs or ExternalQuestion in Mechanical Turk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

First of all I must say I am totally new to MT so forgive me if I am thinking in a totally wrong way.

I have to create a task for workers where they have to classify a sentence if it is spam or if it falls into a certain category. I will have about 2500 sentences to classify a day.

What is the best way to use the API to do this. I understand how to create a HIT using the API, but it is my understanding that I can't create a recurrent HIT that changes itself once each of the sentence is classified. Do I need to create 2500 HITs?

I researched and found out about the External Question which I can setup in my server and make it change with each form submit.

In that case will it be just 1 HIT? is that the correct way to do this?

I am confused in the dynamic part of MT.

Any tip, documentation (updated) or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want to create separate HITs.

If you create an single External HIT (hosted on your server), a
 MTurk Worker who takes your HIT will not be eligible to take another
    task (e.g. a classification task) since Workers are not allowed to
    take a single HIT more than once. However, if you create separate
    HITs, a Worker can take as many of them as they wish, which is
    probably what you want.

You are correct that you cannot automatically change a HIT
    dynamically unless it is run on your own server.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no issue with creating lots and lots of HITs? Is that common behavior to create thousands of HITs?

Comment: Yes...many Hits is normal.  PS. If you like the answer please mark it as correct.